# Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

Could anybody help me to convert to Mathematica 11.0?

```
 `g = FromAdjacencyMatrix[{{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}}]
HamiltonianQ[g]
tour = TravelingSalesman[g]
edges = Partition[tour, 2, 1]
ShowGraph[Highlight[g, {edges}, HighlightedEdgeColors -> {Red}],
VertexStyle -> Disk[.05]]
SetOptions[Arrow, HeadShape -> Automatic, HeadScaling -> Absolute, 
HeadCenter -> .8];
Show[GraphicsArray[
Block[{$DisplayFunction = Identity},
{
ShowGraph[g, VertexColor -> Black, VertexStyle -> Disk[.07]],
Graphics[{PointSize[.06], 
  ShowGraph[g, VertexColor -> Black, VertexStyle -> Disk[.07]][[
   1]], ShowGraph[FromOrderedPairs[edges], EdgeColor -> Red][[
    1]] /. Point[l_] :> {}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]
}   ]]]`
```

Can it be easily converted to a newer version?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It can mostly be easily converted. See `AdjacencyGraph`, `HamiltonianGraphQ`, `FindShortestTour`, and `HighlightGraph`. The difficulty comes in converting the undirected edges to directed.

Answer (score 5):

So the adaption is easy, but not entirely trivial so I'll post it here.

```
g =
  AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
     1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
     1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}}];
HamiltonianGraphQ[g];
tour = FindShortestTour[g][[2]];
edges =
  Map[
    {
      # -> DirectedEdge @@ #,
      Reverse[#] -> DirectedEdge @@ #
      } &,
    UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[tour, 2, 1]
    ] // Flatten;
HighlightGraph[
 EdgeList[g] /. edges,
 Values[edges]
 ]
```

[image: asdasdasd]

The only non-trivial bit was converting the [`UndirectedEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UndirectedEdge.html) into [`DirectedEdge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectedEdge.html).

That was still pretty easy though through a `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Can someone expand function FindShortestTour[g][[2]] because we can't use ready function from Mathematica?

Comment: @Monika it’s just how Mathematica solves the traveling salesman problem. It’s the native function.